# Remainder theorem for polynomials:

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> What's the remainder of  $$F(x)=ax^6+bx^4+cx^2$$ upon division by $x^2-9,$ given that $F(3)=2$ ?

$$F (x)=H(x)(x-3)(x+3)+Dx+E$$

$$F (3)=2\to 2D+E=2H$$

What to do now?

Comment: Hint:  we must have $F(x)=q(x)\times (x^2-9)+r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is linear (or constant).  All you need to find $r(x)$ are two values and you've been handed one.

Comment: What have you actually tried to do? (other than post the problem?)

Comment: @lulu i already did that,  What's next?

Comment: @mdave16  Applying remainder theorem and get  a linear equation ,

Comment: So, play with it. All you need is one more value for $r(x)$ and, really, there is an obvious candidate.

Comment: $F (-3)$ since $F(x)$ is an Even function?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot,  i have done that , but got confused by the choices of the problem,  the answer  $2$ is not there !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you should have got is $F(3)=3D+E=2$.

Evaluating at $-3$ should give the same result, since all terms of $F$ have even degree ($x^6, x^4, x^2$). That implies that $F(-3)=F(3)=2$. Therefore $-3D+E=2$. From these two equations we get $E=2$ and $D=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $F$ is a polynomial in $x^2$ too and that's the divisor too. Applying the remainder theorem on that gives you that the remainder is the value at the point $x^2 = 9$, that is $2$.